# nginx server cannot restart using service nginx start

Tags: nginx, centos

This is my error.log

```
2016/07/01 07:38:17 [emerg] 30759#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 07:48:02 [emerg] 30806#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 07:48:44 [emerg] 30832#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 08:07:36 [emerg] 30913#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 08:07:44 [emerg] 30939#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 08:07:49 [emerg] 30964#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 08:13:54 [emerg] 31138#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
2016/07/01 09:52:49 [emerg] 31735#0: getpwnam("nginx") failed
```

And this is my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location / {
        }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you’re compiling Nginx from source, you might be specifying the user and group flags at compile time.

If this is the case, you need to ensure that the users actually exist when you attempt to start Nginx.

How to fix getpwnam(“nginx”) failed

It’s easy to fix this issue, simply create the specified user (in this case, ‘nginx’) by issuing the following command:

**useradd nginx**

If you would prefer to create the user without a home directory, just add the --no-create-homeflag, as such:

**useradd --no-create-home nginx**

Answer (score 1):

At last I found out the solutions by myself.

I used `nginx -t` which shows that I don't have any syntax error in my code.

Then I used

```
user nobody; // in my nginx.conf
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

your nginx.conf is missing the user directive http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user

if that doesn't work what does the command "journalctl -xe" output ?

Comment: such question it is better to be done by commenting OP's question directly